# How to empty uint array after value is assigned?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, arrays

Here is an `uint` array defined in smart contract:

```
uint256[] public bidderItemID;
```

And `bidderItemID` is assigned value in contract:

```
bidderItemID = [1,2,3];
```

How can I empty `bidderItemID` after it is assigned a value? That is, `bidderItemID.length` is `0` and there is no element in `bidderItemID`. I tried `bidderItemID=[]` and it throws an error.

Comment: Note that, if you have a large array, it's probably not worth it to reset the array, because of the high gas costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `delete` an array to achieve your goal. See the following code as an example.

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;


contract Test {
    uint256[] public bidderItemID;
    
    function setBidderItemID() public {
        bidderItemID = [1,2,3];
    }
    
    function deleteBidderItemID() public {
        delete bidderItemID;
    }
}
```